# PHP function return doesn't work

Tags: php

I'm writing a code for work, to connect with elements by telnet to get from them some configuration options. For one function I have problem because it doesn't return value that I'm expecting. Here is this code:

```
function checkLogin ($element, &$handle, $lastElement, $node=null, &$error=null) {
    $ip = "127.0.0.1";
    $port = "31";
    include('query.php');

    if($serverip[$element]!==$serverip[$lastElement]){
        if($handle) {fclose($handle);}
        $handle = fsockopen($ip, $port, $error, $errstr, 10);
    }
    if (!$handle) { $error="Can't connect to server: ".$ip; return false;}
    else {
        if($element!==$lastElement){
            if(is_null($node)) {$loginElement=$element;}
            else {$loginElement=$node;}

            $out="req ne:name=".$loginElement;
            $error=query($handle,$out);
            if($error[0]!=0) {return false;}
            echo "first\n";
        }
        echo "second\n";
    }
    echo "third\n";
    return true;
}
```

If everything is okey the function return true, and i can see:
    first
    second
    third

But when error[0]==1 then function still return true and I can see something like this:
    second
    third

Do you know what can be the problem?

Comment: Is `$error` supposed to be a string or an array? You use it both ways in this function.

Comment: I use it as array. But in that case it really doesn't matter because it's almost always `true`.

Comment: If it's an array, why do you have `$error="Can't connect to server: ".$ip;`?

Comment: Correct it to `$error[0] = 1;$error[1] = "Can't connect to server: ".$ip;` at it haven't change anything :( it's not the case.

Comment: Where are you echoing these things, to a web page or something else?

Answer (score 1):

If `$element === $lastElement` the `return false` statement is never called. Your output will be

```
second
third
```

in that case.

Comment: I agree on that, but it is not that problem. When i add `if($error[0]!=0) {echo "zero";return false;}` then it show `zero second third`. `first` does not appear.

Comment: Your function is being called twice. First time displaying "zero" and returning false, second time displaying "second" and "third" returning true. The second time `$element === $lastElement`.